# Installation doesn't re-install after deletion

Tags: azure, azure-notificationhub

I've added an installation. After deleting it, I can't re-add it.

If I list the registrations via the "Device Registrations" tab in Visual Studio, it says that there are no registrations and no notification arrives at the device if sent.

Does it remember previous installations and not allow you to re-add them?

Comment: Is this for an iOS device or Android device or something else? Are you registering from the device or via your server? If you register the device and check registered devices before trying to send a notification, does the device show up? Notification Hub will remove registrations that are invalid (e.g. a debug/sandbox app install registered to a production push notification service) or expired (Android devices get new registrations every time you build/run).

Comment: It was for iOS and installed from a server. I deleted a prior installation and then couldn't re-register. Although it was possible to do so after a while. No such issue occurs with registrations - which is why I'm using them instead. And in order to avoid duplicates, I'm checking to see if they're already registered first.